# umbraco 7: get property value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco7

I am using umbraco 7 ASP.NET C# MVC 4.

Im trying to use the new umbraco, so far its been ok, but i need to get a property of one of my pages i set up.

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
     var homePage = CurrentPage.AncestorsOrSelf(1).First();

     var menuItems = homePage.Children.Where("isMenu == true");

}
<!-- Nav -->

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 top-menu-container">
    <ul>
        @* If the Url of the current page is "/" then we want to add the class "current_page_item" *@
        @* Otherwise, we set the class to null, that way it will not even be added to the <li> element *@
        <li>
            <div onclick="location.href='/';"  class="col-md-2 metro-container" style="background-color:#@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("navigationColor")" >
                <img class="menu-img" src="../../media/1001/home.png" alt="" />
                Home
            </div>
        </li>

        @foreach (var item in menuItems)
        {
            @* If the Id of the item is the same as the Id of the current page then we want to add the class "current_page_item" *@
            @* Otherwise, we set the class to null, that way it will not even be added to the <li> element *@
            
            <li>
                <div onclick="location.href='@item.Url';"  class="col-md-2 metro-container" style="background-color:#@item.Content.GetPropertyValue("navigationColor")" >
                    <img class="menu-img" src="../../media/1001/home.png" alt="" />
                    @item.Name
                </div>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

So the first "li" outside the loop i simply get the models content Getproperty method which surely enough gets me any property i tell it too.

However the loop i have although goes through the current pages children, i cant seem to get a specific property.

Makes it worse is intellicense Isn't working as its all runtime.

The line in question is

```
<div onclick="location.href='@item.Url';"  class="col-md-2 metro-container" style="background-color:#@item.Content.GetPropertyValue("navigationColor")" >
```

I need to get the color that was set on the page from the navigationColor control.

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big derp on my side.

The item var in the foreach loop already has property's contained in the item.

all you need to do is

```
item.NameofYourPropertyAlias
```

and that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me:

```
item[index].GetProperty("name").Value
```

Answer (score 1):

> Makes it worse is intellicense Isn't working as its all runtime.

The problem is that you're using dynamic model instead of the strongly typed kind.

Instead of using `CurrentPage` you can use `Model.Content`.

So instead of:

`var homePage = CurrentPage.AncestorsOrSelf(1).First();`

Use:

`var homePage = Model.Content.AncestorOfSelf(1);`

Intellisense will then work after you type a stop after `homePage`.

I would also strongly recommend inputting `using Umbraco.web` with the rest of your using statements at the top of the template. This should further improve intellisense, and allow you to see methods such as `.GetPropertyValue<T>(string alias)`.

You should then be able to use `item.GetPropertyValue<string>("navigationColor")`.

Answer (score -2):

```
item.NameofYourPropertyAlias
```

this is the proper use of item while looping